# Find Object in Array with multiple Keywords Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, search, find

Is there a easy way to find a Object in an Array with multiple keywords?

I have an Array. I want to find the Objects, that has all the keywords, im looking for in the first field of the array.

I hope you can help me :D

```
"new":[ 
     { 
        "name":"Test Product to practice keyword search",
        "id":304613,
        "image_url":"dhoiqwhjdoiqwd",
        "image_url_hi":"ndoiqwjdqowdmqpow",
        "price":200,
        "sale_price":0,
        "new_item":true,
        "position":1,
        "category_name":"Test",
        "price_euro":20,
        "sale_price_euro":0
     }

String keywords[] = {"Product", "keyword", "search"};
```

I want to find the Object in the array where all keywords are matching the name.

Comment: What "keywords"? What "objects"?

Comment: do you mean like looking for specific strings?

Comment: hashset or hashmap, depending on what you want to do

Comment: I have an array. I want to find all indexes, where array[0] contains all keywords im looking for:

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: " I want to find all indexes, where array[0] contains all keywords" - just can't understand this

Comment: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html @SiXon look for some guidance here

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate in your main array, then get the object, I don't know if the object is an string or hashmap or a list or an array, but guessing is an array, you can get the `secondArray[0]` (the `name` field), this is an string, then you can use the `contains` method of the `String` class to see that field contains the keywords that you want to validate.

Thats all I can say based in your explanation.